# Exclude name from list using RegEx

Tags: php, regex

How can I exclude a name from a list using a regular expression?

Data:

```
$subject=
"Damon Carson Stovall,
Bret Roman Mikulak,
Jack Filiberto Quirke,
Elroy Forrest Jarnagin,
Ulysses Wiley Cregger,
Brent Greg Jonah,
Bret Armand Daylong,
Ned Numbers Vandell,
Bret Alden Cutlip,
Bret Chung Markie,";
```

Regular expression:

```
// Select anyone with the first name of Bret
$pattern = "/Bret /";
```

My current solution:

```
// Loop through & Skip any line that matches Bret.
$subject_array = explode(",",$subject);

foreach($subject_array as $line)
  if(!preg_match($pattern, $line))
    echo "$line<br>";
```

Comment: your code seems to be working just fine..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,you can select lines that do not have `Bret` as it's name

```
/^(?!Bret\b).*$/im
```

---

`i` is an ignore case option

`m` is a multiline option

`^` depicts start of the string

`\b` depicts a non word `boundary`

`(?!Bret\b)` is a `negative lookahead`

So `^(?!Bret\b).*$` would select `.*` a string only if the lookahead is true...i.e if the string doesn't start with `Bret`!

Comment: How do you expect him to know what is `multiline option!` ... a good example would help the OP better

Comment: since `/m` is used, there is no need for `explode` and `foreach` then, am I getting it right?

Comment: @Geo i am not a `php developer` but you need to use only `preg_match`..it's `3rd` argument gets all the matches

Answer (score 0):

Since your pattern is so simple, according to the "Notes" box on the [preg_match() manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) you should be rather using `strpos()` or `stripos()` as they are faster:

```
<?

$subject = '
    Damon Carson Stovall,
    Bret Roman Mikulak,
    Jack Filiberto Quirke,
    Elroy Forrest Jarnagin,
    Ulysses Wiley Cregger,
    Brent Greg Jonah,
    Bret Armand Daylong,
    Ned Numbers Vandell,
    Bret Alden Cutlip,
    Bret Chung Markie,';

$pattern = 'Bret ';

$subject_array = explode(',', $subject);

foreach($subject_array as $line)
    if (strpos(trim($line), $pattern) !== 0)
        echo $line . '<br />';
```